# Copy file to non-project directory after webpack compliation

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack

I want to develop a React app for work in a directory and copy the bundle file over to a local instance of our website, which runs on a Django backend in a different directory on my local file system. But, of course, I can quickly develop in one directory and copy the bundle to another directory using my file system. Still, I was hoping to automate this each time I compiled.

I have written a plugin for my webpack config file and can read the bundle and write it to a separate file within the project directory (using the fs package). Still, I can't find a way to write the copy to a different directory on my file system. So it either ends up in the project directory I am compiling from, or I get an error.

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Is such a thing possible? For example, I suppose I could write the bundle to the other directory in the first place and not copy it if the webpack output can write to a different location.

Here is the code for my plugin in my `webpack.config.js` so far. In this example, I was trying to write it to the desktop for testing, but ultimately I would like to put it in a different directory.

```
class Copy {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('Copy', (compilation) => {
    //const file = compilation.getAsset('bundle.js')
    //console.log(file.name)
    let string = fs.readFileSync('./static/js/bundle.js')
    fs.writeFile('/Users/<username>/Desktop/bundle.js', string, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(err)
    })
  })
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple options for the path in the `fs.writeFile` function such as the whole absolute path `C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/bundle.js` and have tried it with and without the leading `/` though I believe it needs one if I don't provide the drive letter.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the path should actually be. I am running WSL2 on Windows 10 and compiling via webpack on a linux terminal. If I provide the full directory using WSL syntax

`/mnt/c/Users/<username>/Desktop/bundle.js`

for example, I can write the bundle where it needs to go.